# LaTeX Ugly Line Above References

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

When generating my LaTeX document (RevTex 4.1) using TeXShop on Mac OSX 10.10.3 the document generates a rather ugly line above my references but below the section heading.

[image: Reference in Question]

This is the code I am using to generate my references:

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
floatfix,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{gensymb} %symbols eg. \degree
\usepackage[numbered]{Files/mcode} %Allow import of MATLAB code

\begin{document}
%References
\clearpage %Put references on separate page
\onecolumngrid %Make references entire page
\section{References}
\bibliography{Files/Bibliography.bib} %"bibliography" -> bibliography file name
\end{document}
```

Any help is removing this line or getting a prettier line would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That "rather ugly line" is inserted by the document class. If you don't like, you should probably consider changing document classes. A separate comment: With this document class, you shouldn't be using the instruction `\section{References}` anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding

```
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}
```

to the preamble removes the separator and replaces it with REFERENCES

Source:
http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2006-08/msg00708.html