# Showing a references section header using BibTeX and revtex4-1

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I am using the revtex-4 document class. The `bibliography` command forms a references section, but there is no section title. Here is what it looks like:

[image: references are listed under a line]

How can I add a "References" header underneath the horizontal bar and above the references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a 100% answer to your question, but according to [LaTeX Ugly Line Above References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246120/latex-ugly-line-above-references) you can use

```
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}
```

in your preamble to remove the separator and replace it with REFERENCES.