# Change REVTeX ugly line above references

Tags: revtex

In [LaTeX Ugly Line Above References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246120/latex-ugly-line-above-references), it is noted that REVTeX adds an ugly line above the references. The line is ugly because it is rasterized and looks pixelated.

[image]

The linked question and answer explains that we can remove the line through:

```
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}}
```

Can we instead replace the line with a smooth, non-pixelated (perhaps vector) version? Perhaps using tikz, though the simpler the better.

This MWE produces the line:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\begin{document}
\bibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide code for a minimal example. You could add an ornament from a font, for example. Or `pgfornaments`.

Comment: yes, good idea, mwe added. something like that, although the pgfornaments looks a bit too decorative

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me no output at all. Do you know what this is called? There's a special name for this kind of line, but I can't remember it. There was a question about it somewhere ....